# Como faço para que o codigo encontre as posições que x se repete e coloque-as no output um por linha? Python

Tags: python

Como faço para que, no código a seguir, os valores que mostram a posição em que o x se repete fiquem cada uma por linha? Tirando o colchete e a virgula.

```
from collections import defaultdict
n = int(input(''))
vetor = []
for c in range(n):
    if n >=1 and n <= 100:
        vetor.append(int(input()))
x = int(input(''))
if x in vetor:
    repete = vetor.count(x)
    print(repete)
posições = defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(vetor):
    posições[x].append(i)
for x in posições:
    if len(posições[x]) > 1:
        print(str(posições[x]).strip('[]'))
```

Supondo que meu N seja 5, minha lista 2,2,2,3,2 e o x seja 2, a saída está sendo essa:

```
4 #numero de vezes que o X se repete
0,1,2,4 #posições que o X se encontra repetido
```

Comment: Objetivo do código é qual? Ta bem confuso. Mas vou arriscar que é checar numeros repetidos numa lista, mas tem umas restrições (olhando o código), parece um exercicio...

Comment: Preciso fazer um conjunto de tamanho N , apos isso, dar os N valores. Com isso, preciso fazer que um X que eu coloco seja identificado no conjunto, depois, é preciso q eu fale quantas vezes ele repete(coisa que consegui fazer) e em quais posições ele repete. Tudo tem que estar em linhas diferentes no output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer imprimir uma posição por linha, faça um `for` e imprima cada elemento, um por vez.

Outro detalhe é que não precisa usar `defaultdict`. Se quer apenas as posições em que um elemento ocorre, faça um *loop* simples, compare o elemento com o valor e guarde a posição na lista de posições:

```
vetor = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
x = 2
posições = []
for i, n in enumerate(vetor):
    if n == x:
        posições.append(i)

for i in posições:
    print(i)
```

A saída é:

```
0
1
2
4
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
vetor = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
x = 2

# usando list comprehension
posições = [ i for i, n in enumerate(vetor) if n == x ]

print('\n'.join(map(str, posições)))
```

E também mostrei outra alternativa para imprimir, usando [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) - no caso, ele junta os elementos da lista colocando o `\n` (quebra de linha) entre eles. O detalhe é que tive que usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para converter os números para string, caso contrário o `join` dá erro.

Comment: Deu certinho! Muito obrigado!!!